# when using onclick metheod should show the picture and the sound together

Tags: java, android

As you can see I have made an image clickable and it should display pics and also the sound. but they both wont match. Here is my code.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView home;
    private Integer images[] = {R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.ten};
    int current_index = 0;
    int[] clips= { R.raw.one, R.raw.two, R.raw.three };
    private int currImage = 0;
    private TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        home = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagehome);

        home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Main3Activity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

        setInitialImage();
        setImageRotateListener();    
    }

    private void setImageRotateListener(){
        final ImageView right = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, clips[current_index]);
        right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                currImage++;
                if (currImage == 3) {
                    currImage = 0;
                }    

                setCurrentImage();

                current_index++;
                if(current_index == 3){
                    current_index =0;
                }

                mediaPlayer.start();                    
            }
        });
    }

    private void setInitialImage(){
        setCurrentImage();
    }

    private void setCurrentImage() {    
        final ImageView display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        display.setImageResource(images[currImage]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer - Increase the values in `onClick()` using: `currImage = ++currImage / 3;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaPlayer cannot be used for something like this. It takes a few seconds to begin to play. For low-latency playback you should use [SoundPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) instead. Here is [one of many tutorials](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-android-s-soundpool-class-a-tutorial.html) on using SoundPool.

Comment: Sorry I'm a complete beginner so don't understand what you mean. Sorry to bother. Just started learning about android development

Comment: What I mean is from the time you call mediaPlayer.start() until the time you actually head sound coming from your phone will be a few seconds. If you were to play the audio with SoundPool instead, it would play almost instantly.

Comment: ok another question. my current index is playing only one file. its not playing the rest

Comment: Thats because you always tell it to play clips[0]. setImageRotateListener runs once, and loads up MediaPlayer with clip[0] with this line MediaPlayer.create(this, clips[current_index]. Then then when you call play it will just play what was already loaded. If you plan to stick with media player (which I don't recommend) then you would need to load a new one right before you call play.

Comment: I think I should stick to learning more. But really thnx. helped me to think out of the box but haven't solved my problems yet. Thank you. would be great if you could point me to a direction where I could learn more about android and Java. really need a lot of help here. Thnx

Comment: Google and Udacity has a free Android development course: https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853